# Removing element from xml vb

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have an xml file in which I have to remove specific elements. In this case when given a docotor ID that specific doctor is to be removed. The xml looks like this:

```
<Doctor>
<DoctorID>1</DoctorID>
<FirstName>John</FirstName>
<LastName>Doe</LastName>
<Specialty>Family</Specialty>
</Doctor>
<Doctor>
<DoctorID>2</DoctorID>
<FirstName>James</FirstName>
<LastName>Kameron</LastName>
<Specialty>Obstetric</Specialty>
</Doctor>
```

My vb code looks like this:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim doc As New Xml.XmlDocument
    doc.Load("..\..\..\Doctors.xml")

    Dim ID As String
    ID = DGV_1.CurrentRow.ToString()

    Dim DoctorNodes = doc.SelectNodes("//Doctor//DoctorID")
    For Each elem As Xml.XmlElement In DoctorNodes
        If elem.InnerText = ID.ToString Then
            elem.RemoveAll()
            ''elem.ParentNode.RemoveChild(elem)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    MessageBox.Show(doc.OuterXml)

End Sub
```

But it seems I am lost, anyone know what I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

i'm new to vb and xml,too but i read something that might help you:
you can search for a xml node that has a sub-node with a specific value and then revmoe that node.

like: Doctors/Doctor[DoctorID=1]

```
Dim ID as String = Textbox1.Text
Dim DoctorNodes = doc.SelectNodes("Doctor[DoctorID=" & ID & "]")
doc.RemoveChild(DoctorNodes(0))
```

have a look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath